# Cesium camera.setView to rectangle clipping the rectangle

Tags: cesium, extents

My application allows users to add GeoJSON objects to a cesium map.  If the GeoJSON has a `bbox`, it will set the view to the bounding box:

```
const destination = Cesium.Rectangle.fromDegrees(
    bbox[0], bbox[1], bbox[3], bbox[4]);
this.viewer.camera.setView({destination});
```

My *naïve* expectation is that the entirety of the GeoJSON object would be shown in the view, but that is not what I am experiencing.  It appears that if the `bbox` has the same (or quite similar) aspect ratio to the div containing the cesium map then it behaves as I want, but if not then the view only shows a portion of the GeoJSON object.  For example, this is what I am seeing:

[image]

And this is what I would expect to see:

[image]

*Note that the first image is exactly as rendered after `setView`, the second image is shown after manually zooming out, and the blue/white stripped box is the `bbox` drawn to demonstrate the issue.*

---

Further investigation seems to indicate that if the `bbox` is width constrained, then Cesium will zoom out to include the entire `bbox`, but not if height constrained.  To say it another way, if the `bbox` is tall and skinny, I have a problem, but if short and fat, I don't...

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to find a solution using Turf, for example http://turfjs.org/docs/#square might do the trick.